# Is there a simple method to undo a click event?

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling

I'm learning basic javascript events and would like to know how I can undo a click event.

I have a simple event that changes text using the `changeText` method.

That's only half of what I wan't to do. As user experience is important , I'd like for this event to be "undone" when the user clicks anywhere on the page.

**So essentially after the user has clicked the button and changed text, they should be able to click anywhere on the page causing the text to go back to its default "I will change".**

```js
const changeText = () => {
    const p = document.querySelector('p');

    p.textContent = "I changed because of an event listener.";
}

// Listen for click event
const button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', changeText);
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>

<p>I will change.</p>
```

Comment: Can't you just listen for clicks on the rest of the page and revert the change in the page click handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add another function `revertText` which undoes the change, and call that when the `document` is clicked. If you do this, however, it will be triggered when you click the button as well. So, in order to only tigger the button event when the button is clicked use `e.stopPropagation()` to stop the `document` click event from also executing.

See working example below:

```js
const changeText = e => { // Pass event (e) argument into function
    e.stopPropagation(); // Stop the document click event from running
    const p = document.querySelector('p');

    p.textContent = "I changed because of an event listener.";
}

const revertText = () => {
  const p = document.querySelector('p');
  p.textContent = "I will change";
}

// Listen for click event
const button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', changeText);
document.addEventListener('click', revertText) // Add second event listener on the document
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>

<p>I will change.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can attach an eventListener to the document:

```
document.addEventListener('click', changeTextBack)


changeTextback (event) {
// use event target to make sure he is not clicking on button
// use same methods as in changeText method to target element and alter text
}
```

The document represents the entire page. You could also attach it to the window.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document
https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/Window

was this helpful?

Answer (score 0):

So you just want another click event but on another object.
In your HTML you have to make some sort of container and then:

```
const changeTextBack = () => {
    const p = document.querySelector('p');

    p.textContent = "I will change.";
}

// Listen for click event
const buttonContainer = document.querySelector('button-container');
buttonContainer.addEventListener('click', changeTextBack);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind an event on the document and store the default text somewhere globally. See the solution below:

```js
let obj = {}; // object to store the def text of "p"
const changeText = (event) => { // pass the event object here
  event.stopPropagation(); // stop the event to propagate back to parent
  const p = document.querySelector('p');
  if (event.target.tagName === "BUTTON") { // if clicked item is button
    if (!obj['p']) {
      obj['p'] = p.textContent; // store the def text in obj
    }
    p.textContent = "I changed because of an event listener."; // change the text
  } else { // otherwise
    p.textContent = obj.p; // change back the def text
  }
}

// Listen for click event
const button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', changeText);
document.addEventListener('click', changeText);
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>

<p>I will change.</p>
```

Comment: If you click the button multiple times and then try and click off the button the text doesn't revert back

Comment: Nice, no worries :)